# id is not updated when using junit tests

Tags: jpa, junit, spring-transactions

I have a table (`person_id`) for keeping the sequence.

```
@TableGenerator(name = "person_gen",
        table = "person_id",
        pkColumnName = "seq_name",
        valueColumnName = "seq_num",
        pkColumnValue = "person_id",
        initialValue = 100,
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "person_gen")
```

When running the test cases I got new id for the entity but `seq_num` is not updated after test is done. Always got same id, whenever I run the test. Each test case is annotated with `@Transactional`.

I can see the sql output that `seq_num` is updated, but probably that value is reverted with the transaction.

Any way to have always to increment the id regardless of the outcome of the transaction.

UPDATE:

I'm using:

`@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true, transactionManager = "transactionManager")`

`org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using EclipseLink as JPA provider, this configuration will make generating id's be done in different connection. In this case ID always will be incremented in the sequence table.

`<prop key="eclipselink.jdbc.sequence-connection-pool">true</prop>`.